# PDO Prepared statement insert 1 instead of string

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I have this query which no matter what `$relocation['persons_id']` is, updates `residents` to `1`.

The following code will in this example echo `11,13`, but set `residents` to `1`:

```
    $query = $db->prepare('UPDATE `apartments` SET `residents` = :persons_id AND `occupation_date` = :occupation_date WHERE `id` = :apartments_id');
    echo $relocation['persons_id']."<br>\n";
    $query->bindParam(':persons_id', $relocation['persons_id']);
    $query->bindParam(':occupation_date', $relocation['occupation_date']);
    $query->bindParam(':apartments_id', $relocation['apartments_id']);
    $query->execute();
```

The field `residents` has the datatype `varchar(200)`.

Can you please explain what i am doing wrong?

Comment: try to convert datatype to int (11) and check once. please

Comment: What is the output of: `echo $relocation['persons_id']`

Comment: @Rizier123 it is as stated in the question 11,13

Comment: @anant kumar singh as i try to insert a string, int will probably not a possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies here

```
SET `residents` = :persons_id AND `occupation_date` = :occupation_date
```

which means, for the operator precedence

```
UPDATE `apartments` SET `residents` = (:persons_id AND `occupation_date` = :occupation_date) WHERE `id` = :apartments_id
```

so `residents` is updated to a boolean value (0/1).

Maybe you want use `,`

```
UPDATE `apartments` SET `residents` = :persons_id, `occupation_date` = :occupation_date WHERE `id` = :apartments_id
```

Comment: That seems so correct, I must need some sleep. I will test and return.

Comment: I experienced this gotcha the other way around. In PHP `AND` comes *after* `=` (as opposed to `&&`) which left me really confused until I read the documentation.